# SQL: Update on join, in standards?

Tags: sql

I know that most sql server software allows you to do "A Update on a Join", but I am wondering, is this in the SQL standards?
(eg. can I assume that any software package allows this?)

Note: I am asking this because I am writing a database library that should be easily extensible to database software that is not included in the original build. As such there's no point in answering with a remark such as "a, b, c and b all allow that - together they make up the lionshare of the market, so you can assume that all software packages allow that". No, I am interested in whether it is in the standards or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the ANSI SQL-92 standard, an UPDATE on JOINed tables is NOT part of the standards; See http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt sections 13.9 and 13.10 (you'll have to search for 391, the page number).

I tried to find an ANSI 2003 standard, but the closest I came was here:  www.wiscorp.com/sql_2003_standard.zip (a late draft).  There was no substantial difference between the two in regards to the UPDATE statement and JOIN syntax.

Stu

Answer (score 5):

If I understand the question right, I think the answer is no, there is no standard "update based on a join". The [postgres manual page for UPDATE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) includes this under "Compatibility":

> This command conforms to the SQL standard, except that the FROM and RETURNING clauses are PostgreSQL extensions, as is the ability to use WITH with UPDATE.
>
> Some other database systems offer a FROM option in which the target table is supposed to be listed again within FROM. That is not how PostgreSQL interprets FROM. Be careful when porting applications that use this extension.

While this doesn't explicitly say there *isn't*, the Compatibility notes in that manual generally note when there is a related, but not identical, feature in the standard. What's more, the mention of other systems with different behaviour demonstrates that if there is a standard, you can't rely on it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You're presuming that all software packages adhere to ANSI SQL Standards.....in reality, none of them that I'm aware of adhere completely to the standards.

If you're looking to adhere to ANSI SQL standards, the best place to start would be with the documented standards themselves.  Here's the SQL-92 document:

http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

Comment: I am not under that impression.
As far as I know all widely used software provides this functionality. If, in addition to that, it is in the standard, I can use it and I'll be able to support any sql software that supports the standards well enough. If they don't support the function while it is in the standard, their bad.
Now, if it is not in the standards then it is a different story. In that case I simply used a function that some big company made up and some others followed, and for that reason I will not be able to support sql software who did not follow suit.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will look through it - though it is a pain to find anything you are looking for in it, so if anyone would happen to know, that would still be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Careful now, folks.  Writing truly portable code is much more difficult than you would imagine and you also have to be willing to give up a lot in the areas of performance, ease of coding/maintenance, and readability.  Just declare and use one variable in, say, SQL Server and your code is no longer truly portable.  Write an audit trigger and I can guarantee that your trigger won't be portable between Oracle, SQL Server, and several other popular engines.  And, it should really matter because it's not actually rocket science in any RDBMS (well, except maybe for writing a joined UPDATE in Oracle without using MERGE {which is standard but not portable, yet}).

Also, don't forget there are two basic types of SQL.  That which supports the single row nature of most front-end code and that of batch code.  If you really want your batch code to perform well, you'll use many of the "proprietary extensions" to the database engine you're using to efficiently process sometimes billions of rows overnight... the same night. ;-)

Be careful when aiming at writing code for "true" portability.  You might end up with a tangled mess that's a whole lot slower than you might have ever imagined.