# How to adapt this MySql query for PervasiveSql?

Tags: mysql, sql, pervasive, pervasive-sql

How can I adapt the following update query from MySql to PervasiveSql?

```
UPDATE Rx_Annotations 
INNER JOIN User_Master
    ON Usr_Username = Rxa_Usr_Id_Added 
SET Rxa_Usr_Id_Added = Usr_Id 
WHERE Rxa_Usr_Id_Added = 'WEB'
```

Comment: I don't know Pervasive, but that's really basic, standard SQL. What problem do you have with it?

Comment: @Barmar I think his only problem is he is not specifying FROM. I'm pretty sure that Pervasive expects FROM if you are using joins

Comment: @Stivan I don't see it [here](http://cs.pervasive.com/forums/p/7351/26559.aspx)

Comment: @Barmar https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html here is where I checked. I assume you don't need `from` if you are not including additional tables

Comment: @Stivan That's Postgres, but I guess Pervasive copied that syntax. Apparently both syntaxes are extensions to the ANSI standard. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517579/sql-update-on-join-in-standards

Comment: @Barmar Oops. I was searching for psql and accidentally came across PostgreSQL. But I guess you are right. It seems like their syntax is identical.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Rx_annotations
SET Rxa_Usr_Id_Added = User_Master.Usr_Id
FROM Rx_Annotations 
     INNER JOIN User_Master ON User_Master.Usr_Username = Rx_annotations.Rxa_Usr_Id_Added 
WHERE Rx_Annotations.Rxa_Usr_Id_Added = 'WEB'
```

Comment: Thanks:)

But it has "Error in predicate: Rxa_Usr_Id_Added = 'WEB' " after executing

Comment: @KirillZaychanko I also included link to the documentation if you are trying to convert further update queries.