# Convert mysql update query to a query which support on h2 db

Tags: mysql, h2

I have to write an update query which should work on normal mysql db and h2 database.

This was my original mysql query.

**Query1**

```
UPDATE table1 AS mt, table2 AS et 
    SET mt.country_name = et.country_name, 
    mt.country_continent = et.country_continent 
WHERE mt.id = et.id
```

But h2 db was complaining syntax error for Query1.

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement
>   "update table1 AS mt,[*]table2 AS et as et mt.country_name =
>   et.country_name, mt.country_continent = et.country_continent WHERE
>   mt.id = et.id ; expected "SET"; SQL statement: update table1 AS
>   mt,table2 AS et as et mt.country_name = et.country_name,
>   mt.country_continent = et.country_continent WHERE mt.id = et.id
>   [42001-199]   at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:451)
>     at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427)
>     at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:243)
>     at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:991)    at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.read(Parser.java:4541)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parseUpdateSetClause(Parser.java:1228)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parseUpdate(Parser.java:1223)   at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:943)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:788)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:764)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:683)     at
>   org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:627)  at
>   org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:565)    at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1292)
>     at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:77)
>     at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:349)
>     at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:311)
>     at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)

Then I converted it as follows

**Query2**

```
UPDATE table1 AS mt , table2 as et 
SET (mt.country_name, mt.country_continent ) = 
   ( SELECT et.country_name, et.country_continent   
     FROM table2 AS et 
     WHERE mt.id = et.id  )
```

which I expected to work on both mysql and h2db but this one is throwing syntax error on mysql.

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '(mt.country_name, mt.country_continent)= ( SELECT
>   et.country_name, et.country_co' at line 1 0.00073 sec

Can someone one please help me to convert my *Query1 to a query which support both on mysql and h2db*. I think it should almost look like Query2 but I may be wrong.

Comment: _But h2 db was complaining syntax error for Query1._ SHOW US the error message in its entirity, do not summarise it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Updated the question with the exception. I tried to convert it  and i failed on it and  I don't know how to proceed with that. That's why I posted in SO. Sorry if you think otherwise then I could delete the question.

Comment: OP has added enough details into the question now; Nominating it for reopening @RiggsFolly

Comment: @nantitv Try `UPDATE .. JOIN` syntax: `Update table1 AS t1 JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.id SET t1.country_name = t2.country_name, t1.country_continent = t2.country_continent`  MySQL does not allow `SET (... multiple columns...)` syntax.

Comment: Thnx. I will try and update.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I tried it does not working on h2 db org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "update table1 as mt join[*] table2 as et on mt.id = et.id  set mt.id = et.id  where  et.itemid =123) "; expected "SET"; SQL statement:
UPDATE table1 AS mt JOIN table2 AS et ON mt.id = et.id  set mt.id = et.id  where  et.itemId =123) [42001-199]
 at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:451)
 at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427)
 at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:243)

Comment: I think h2 db does not support join http://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html

Comment: @nantitv Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/44845278/2469308 .. Use two subqueries to set values individually. Like `set a1 = select (....) , a2 = select (..)`. It is inefficient, but should work in both MySQL and H2

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Thnx for the link. It's bit inefficient. Anyway I will try

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness - I have read  here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517579/sql-update-on-join-in-standards that update with join is not in standards and different db will do it in different ways. For eg: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/ in this way and postgres in different way https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/sql-update.html and most of the inmemory db follow as QUERY2 of my question